# Having Javascript issues with JSON data (Destiny 2 API)

Tags: javascript, api, loops, for-loop

I've been trying to wrap my head around my first proper site using JSON data and an API; I'm using Destiny 2's API - but I've now hit a bit of snag.

I'm not sure how to loop through, for example, the `membershipId` of each `Response.characters.data.(?).membershipId`. The `(?)` is dynamic, depending on the original API request, but I'm not sure how to loop through this since it's not in an array.

```
 {
    "Response": {
        "characters": {
            "data": {
                "2305843009301086354": {
                    "membershipId": "4611686018467309748",
                    "membershipType": 4,
                    "characterId": "2305843009301086354",
                    "dateLastPlayed": "2018-08-27T19:22:17Z",
                    "minutesPlayedThisSession": "166",
                    "minutesPlayedTotal": "1251",
                    "light": 300
                },
                "2305843009299512096": {
                    "membershipId": "4611686018467309748",
                    "membershipType": 4,
                    "characterId": "2305843009299512096",
                    "dateLastPlayed": "2018-08-28T22:27:07Z",
                    "minutesPlayedThisSession": "58",
                    "minutesPlayedTotal": "4115",
                    "light": 359
                },
                "2305843009317224837": {
                    "membershipId": "4611686018467309748",
                    "membershipType": 4,
                    "characterId": "2305843009317224837",
                    "dateLastPlayed": "2017-12-08T19:34:05Z",
                    "minutesPlayedThisSession": "12",
                    "minutesPlayedTotal": "12",
                    "light": 10
                }
            },
            "privacy": 1
        },
        "characterUninstancedItemComponents": {},
        "itemComponents": {}
    },
    "ErrorCode": 1,
    "ThrottleSeconds": 0,
    "ErrorStatus": "Success",
    "Message": "Ok",
    "MessageData": {}
}
```

How do I target this? I was expecting something similar to how I'd do an array, something along the lines of:

```
var characterIds = characterData.Response.characters.data;

   for(var i = 0; i < characterIds.length; i++){
     var characterId = characterIds[i];
     var characterMembershipId = characterId.membershipId; 
     console.log(characterMembershipId);
   }
```

Any help would be appreciated here - sorry if my explanations are a bit naff, my terminology isn't great: trying to get to grips and learning things by getting stuck in!

**EDIT:** 
Thanks for the help so far guys, I think I might've done a bad job of explaining what I'm after.

The part I'm trying to get from a For loop is the results of `Response.characters.data`, the random numbers (currently `"2305843009301086354"`, `"2305843009299512096"` and `"2305843009317224837"`)  - which changes depending on the API request so:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "characters": {
            "data": {
                "2305843009301086354": {
                   "characterId": "2305843009301086354",
                },
                "2305843009299512096": {
                    "characterId": "2305843009299512096",
                },
                "2305843009317224837": {
                    "characterId": "2305843009317224837",
                }
```

and then from there, I want to be able to `console.log` the `characterId` for each loop of these `.data` results.

Sorry if that makes even less sense, but I really appreciate the help so far!

**SECOND EDIT:**
Apologies guys, I was being thick - got it working, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the `Object.values` of the `data` property to get to each member object, then extract the `membershipId` of each:

```js
const input={"Response":{"characters":{"data":{"2305843009301086354":{"membershipId":"4611686018467309748","membershipType":4,"characterId":"2305843009301086354","dateLastPlayed":"2018-08-27T19:22:17Z","minutesPlayedThisSession":"166","minutesPlayedTotal":"1251","light":300},"2305843009299512096":{"membershipId":"4611686018467309748","membershipType":4,"characterId":"2305843009299512096","dateLastPlayed":"2018-08-28T22:27:07Z","minutesPlayedThisSession":"58","minutesPlayedTotal":"4115","light":359},"2305843009317224837":{"membershipId":"4611686018467309748","membershipType":4,"characterId":"2305843009317224837","dateLastPlayed":"2017-12-08T19:34:05Z","minutesPlayedThisSession":"12","minutesPlayedTotal":"12","light":10}},"privacy":1},"characterUninstancedItemComponents":{},"itemComponents":{}},"ErrorCode":1,"ThrottleSeconds":0,"ErrorStatus":"Success","Message":"Ok","MessageData":{}}

Object.values(input.Response.characters.data)
  .forEach(({ membershipId }) => {
    console.log(membershipId);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this,
use jquery "for" to iterate over characters and finally print their id

```
var response = {
"Response": {
    "characters": {
        "data": {
            "2305843009301086354": {
                "membershipId": "4611686018467309748",
                "membershipType": 4,
                "characterId": "2305843009301086354",
                "dateLastPlayed": "2018-08-27T19:22:17Z",
                "minutesPlayedThisSession": "166",
                "minutesPlayedTotal": "1251",
                "light": 300
            },
            "2305843009299512096": {
                "membershipId": "4611686018467309748",
                "membershipType": 4,
                "characterId": "2305843009299512096",
                "dateLastPlayed": "2018-08-28T22:27:07Z",
                "minutesPlayedThisSession": "58",
                "minutesPlayedTotal": "4115",
                "light": 359
            },
            "2305843009317224837": {
                "membershipId": "4611686018467309748",
                "membershipType": 4,
                "characterId": "2305843009317224837",
                "dateLastPlayed": "2017-12-08T19:34:05Z",
                "minutesPlayedThisSession": "12",
                "minutesPlayedTotal": "12",
                "light": 10
            }
        },
        "privacy": 1
    },
    "characterUninstancedItemComponents": {},
    "itemComponents": {}
},
"ErrorCode": 1,
"ThrottleSeconds": 0,
"ErrorStatus": "Success",
"Message": "Ok",
"MessageData": {}
};

var data = response;

$characters = data.Response.characters.data;
for($character in $characters)
{
  console.log($characters[$character].membershipId);
}
```